# "Приобрести в подарок" и "подарить" одно и то же?

Tags: семантика, лексикология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, фразы "приобрести в подарок" и "подарить" не являются же равнозначными? Как это можно обоснованно объяснить? Или же они равнозначны?

Answer (score 1):

Это **не** одно и тоже: можно приобрести в подарок (= **купить с намерением** подарить), а затем по какой-то причине не подарить (передумать дарить, не донести в целости и сохранности и т. п.).

Comment: Конечно, слова сами за себя говорят (это я Валерии)!